# How do you scrape a links and images using Goutte

Tags: php, screen-scraping, goutte

I'd like to know how to scrape images using Goutte.
when I run the following code

$client = new Client();

```
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://kings.app/home');

    $crawler->filter('.post-preview')->each(function ($node) {

        $title = "<p>1}}".$node->filter('.post-title')->text()."</p>"."<br>"."<hr>";

        $sub  = "<p>2}}".$node->filter('.post-subtitle')->text()."</p>"."<br>";

        $href = $node->filter('a')->attr("href");
        $image = "<p>".$node->filter('img')->attr("src")."</p>";

        $link ="<a href='$href'>Visit W3Schools</a>";

        echo $image;
        echo $link;
        echo $title;
        echo $sub;
    });
```

I get the following error

The current node list is empty.

But if I remove

```
 $image = "<p>".$node->filter('img')->attr("src")."</p>";
```

and

```
 echo $image;
```

it works fine.

EDIT: If I add a separate crawler function under the above code like this

```
  $crawler->filter('img')->each(function ($node) {


        echo $node->attr('src').'<br>';

    });
```

it prints out the sources

Also, in spite of the error, it still prints out the path. I am using Laravel, so what echo's out is above the error output. Could any one explain how I could get this to work properly so I can scrape the image. thanks

Comment: Can you space your question into separate paragraphs so it is easier to read?